# how many FileTables we can create in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

i am using SQL Server 2012 and would like to implement FileTables feature in application. how many FileTable we can create in one Database in SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of tables allowed in a single database is limited to the total number of object, which can't exceed 2,147,483,647. I've never run across any article that diferentiates between regular tables and file tables.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)